# What is the WM Windows message for Window Maximize/Minimize/Restore?

Tags: c++, winapi, win32gui

I know about `WM_SIZE` and `WM_SIZING`, but is there a message that is sent when the user maximizes or minimizes the window by using system menu?

I need to capture this event in my project and I'm not able to google out what would be the message.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[WM_SIZE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/wm-size) description: Sent to a window after its size has changed. The wParam contains the reason:

> SIZE_MAXIMIZED The window has been maximized. SIZE_MINIMIZED The
>   window has been minimized. SIZE_RESTORED The window has been resized,
>   but neither the SIZE_MINIMIZED nor SIZE_MAXIMIZED value applies.

In short, WM_SIZE is sent no matter what causes the resize. Clicking on the maximize button is equal to selecting the maximize option from the system menu.

If you, for some reason, want to distinguish the mouse click from the menu selection, you can use WM_NCMOUSEMOVE to detect the mouse going to the upper right.

Comment: I need to draw resized bitmap when window get MAXIMIZED, but problem is that it draws wrong (ex. small bitmap instead of large, when window is maximized) so I though it could be solved with capturing this event but still no luck :(

Comment: It depends on the drawing bitmap then. In any  case, you should not draw on WM_SIZE, but on WM_PAINT instead, this ensures that any size is correct (use GetClientRect() inside WM_PAINT).

Comment: BTW, to detect whether the `WM_SIZE` event is a resize or a minimize, you can call [`BOOL IsIconic(HWND)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-isiconic)

Answer (score 7):

### [`WM_SYSCOMMAND`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/menurc/wm-syscommand)

> A window receives this message when the user chooses a command from the Window menu (formerly known as the system or control menu) or when the user chooses the maximize button, minimize button, restore button, or close button.

The `wParam` will be set to `SC_MINIMIZE`, `SC_MAXIMIZE`, etc.